# Counter example to Lp space inclusion

Tags: measure-theory

Thereom: Let $(X,S,\mu)$ be a measure space. If $\mu(X)<\infty$, $1\leq p < q <\infty$, then $L_q\subset L_p$.

But if we take $X=(0,1]$ and take the Lebesgue measure $\mu$, and define $f(x):=\frac{1}{x^{1/3}}$. Then clearly $\mu(X)=1<\infty$, and $f\in L_2$ but $f\notin L_3$, which contradicts the theorem above. But I can't see what I'm missing.

Comment: Indeed, $L_3\subsetneq L_2$, so $L_2\setminus L_3\neq \emptyset$. You exhibited an element of that set.

Comment: @LorenzoQ. But then the theorem would be incorrect?

Comment: No: the theorem implies that $L_3\subset L_2$. This is not a contradiction with $L_3\subsetneq L_2$, which is what you showed.